# Error when instantiating custom queue that inherites from std::queue

Tags: c++

I have a queue that extends the `std::queue`

```cpp
template<typename T, typename Container = std::queue<T>>
    class device_queue : public std::queue<T, Container>
    {
     private:
        flag::state state = flag::state::IDLE;

     public:
        void SetState(const flag::state& _state)
        {
            state = _state;
        }

        flag::state GetState() const
        {
            return state;
        }
    };
```

it being declared:

```cpp
device_queue<Event> cpu_queue;
```

the usage is just using `pop` and `front`, but I keep getting the following error message

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_queue.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Event; _Sequence = std::queue<Event, std::deque<Event, std::allocator<Event> > >; std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::value_type = Event]’:
src/handler.cpp:11:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_queue.h:260:11: error: ‘class std::queue<Event, std::deque<Event, std::allocator<Event> > >’ has no member named ‘push_back’
  260 |       { c.push_back(__x); }
      |         ~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_queue.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::queue<_Tp, _Sequence>::pop() [with _Tp = Event; _Sequence = std::queue<Event, std::deque<Event, std::allocator<Event> > >]’:
src/handler.cpp:92:23:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_queue.h:295:4: error: ‘class std::queue<Event, std::deque<Event, std::allocator<Event> > >’ has no member named ‘pop_front’
  295 |  c.pop_front();
      |  ~~^~~~~~~~~
```

I  am not sure where I am going wrong or how to fix this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you set `std::queue` as the container of your queue. `std::queue` does not support `push_back` or `pop_front`. you can use `std::vector` as your container

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency from `queue` to `queue` when you make a `queue` the container type used in the `queue` and `queue` does not satisfy all the requirements in itself.

I suggest using a `std::deque` as the default container instead, like it is by default for a `queue`.

So instead of

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::queue<T>>
```

make it

```
template<typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
```

[From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue):

> "*The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The container must satisfy the requirements of [SequenceContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SequenceContainer). Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual semantics:*"
>
> - `back()`
> - `front()`
> - `push_back()`
> - `pop_front()`

Comment: I changed the container to `std::deque` and it works now! Thanks!

Comment: @ColinHarker You're welcome. I added further explanations.